# Understanding `sum` function behavior with a boolean expression

Tags: r

Consider this code:

```
x=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,5)
x
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5
sum(x==1,2)
# [1] 5
```

What is `sum(x==1,2)` doing?

Comment: True, but after about a dozen attempts, I gave up. Please change my title for me.

Comment: David, you can't use the word "problem" in a title.  You should review some intro material about R.  `x==1` is considered `TRUE` for the 3 of the elements of `x`.  `TRUE` is mapped to `1L` and `FALSE` to `0L`.  You are taking the sum of 1+1+1+2.

Comment: Frank, nice answer. Don't think I've every stumbled across something like this before. This came up when I was correcting some student work and they should have done sum(data>=40) but they did sum(data==40,50) and I'd never seen that before, so your explanation really will help me explain to this student.

Comment: @David, how are you correcting students work in R if don't even know how to check their code? Functions in R work from inside out. Thus, the first thing you should have done is just to run `x==1` and see what happens. After words you should have tried `class(x==1)`. The last step is to use Google. For example, ["summing logical vector r"](http://www.google.co.il/search?q=boolean&oq=boolean&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2492j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8&gws_rd=ssl#safe=strict&sout=1&q=summing+logical+vector+r). Isn't this process looks basic to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at `help(sum)` we see that all arguments not named `na.rm` will be in the `...` argument, meaning that the function will attempt to add them.

You are passing `sum` the vector `c(x==1, 2)`. In this vector the logical vector returned by `x==1` is converted to numeric type and then the sum is taken.

```
> x
## 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5
> x==1
## TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> c(x==1, 2)
## 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
> sum(c(x==1,2))
## 5
> sum(x==1,2)
## 5
```

Comment: might also be useful to point out that this is equivalent to `sum(x==1)+2`

Comment: Nice answer. This is the first time I've seen something like sum(x==1,2), thinking that it was required to do sum(c(x==1,1)), which I would have understood. Thanks everyone for your help.